# Application developed in .Net Framework 4.5 retargeted to 3.5, but not working on 32 bit Windows XP.

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have developed a small application in VB using Visual Studio 2012 and .Net Framework 4.5 and it does not work with 32 bit Windows XP machine. So I googled that and retargeted the .Net Framework to 3.5 and rebuilt the setup exe. But it again is not working with Windows XP. When I try to run the setup.exe it says `setup.exe is not a valid Win32 application`. 
Does it help if I downgrade my Visual Studio to older version? If so, which one works with every Windows OS?

Comment: Please keep an eye on your spelling and grammar. Many users aren't native speakers (maybe you aren't either) and correct spelling makes reading and understanding your question a lot easier. English is tough stuff (I think Mark Twain said so), but that's no excuse not to use a basic spell checker and fix the most glaring typos.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed .Net Framework 3.5 on Windows XP?

> (Windows 7, Vista & 8 already contains .Net Framework 3.0/older)